# Change website background to an image with button in html

Tags: javascript, html

In my script tag, I have:

```js
function swap() {
  if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('Design/b1.jpeg') != -1) {
    document.getElementById("pic").src = "Design/b1.jpeg";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="Design/b1.jpeg" alt="B1" width="255" height="38" type="button" name="pic" id="pic" onclick="swap();" />
```

Where have I gone wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You miss a "}".

Comment: Press F12 in browser and check error in console.

Comment: Aside from the missing curly brace for the function, your code works.

Answer (score 0):

You miss out a closing brace

```
function swap(){
  if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('Design/b1.jpeg') != -1) {
      document.getElementById("pic").src = "Design/b1.jpeg";
  }
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function swap(){
  if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/d62dd6/fff') != -1) {
      document.getElementById("pic").src = "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/d62dd6/fff";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff" alt="B1" width="100" height="100" type="button" name="pic" id="pic" onclick="swap();" />
```

Comment: I tried this code but the background still doesnt change?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use indentation. Your issue would never happen if you use:

```
function swap()
{
  if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('Design/b1.jpeg') != -1) 
  {
    document.getElementById("pic").src = "Design/b1.jpeg";
  }
} // <= your error
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so much hardcoding? Use a swap function with parameters.

```
function swap(reference, val){
    var elem = document.getElementById(reference);
    if(elem.getAttribute('src') !== val){
        elem.setAttribute('src', val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
  function swap(){
if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('Design/b1.jpeg') != 1) {
    document.getElementById("pic").src = "Design/b1.jpeg";
}
```

I think you want to swap if the urls doesnt match. If not please provide more details